# SSH tunnel to connect two servers via a third

Tags: mysql, port, ssh-tunnel

I've three servers **A** , **B**, and **C**.
Each server is inside a proper network, and server **C** should connect to a mysql DB in server A on port 3306 to perform some tests.

The scenario is as follows:

- Server **C** can communicate with server **B**
- I can ssh to server **B**
- I can ssh to server **A**

Server **A** has a mysql server (obviously), but server **B** has neither a mysql server nor a mysql client.

I've tried the following method:

- Connect **C** to **B:3306**
- Map remote **B:3306** to **local:3337** , via `ssh -R 3306:localhost:3337 b-user@B-server`
- Map **local:3337** to **A:3306** , `ssh -L 3337:localhost:3306 a-user@A-server`

Obviously, I don't understand something about SSH tunnel, but what am I missing?

I'm sure about communication between localhost and server **A** because the mysql client in my localhost can open a connection to server **A** via the ssh tunnel created with `ssh -L 3337:localhost:3306 a-user@A-server`.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I've asked in SuperUser. Thanks for your suggestion.